# Tagging UI hard to tap on iOS 8/iPhone 6

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface, ios-app

The screen area that is visible to tap to add a second tag, after you add the first, is far smaller than 40 points. You have to be very careful or drag up and tap before the tag area retreats to the neutral position.

[image: illustration]

This is also reproduced on the iPhone 5 and 4S on iOS 8. The version of the app is 1.1.0 from the App Store.

Comment: But that isn't an iPhone 6, is it?

Comment: @wumm The screenshot is from iPhone 6. What are you asking?

Comment: but how can that image fit my iPhone 5's screen? (The time position, the size of the keyboard)

Comment: @wumm Here is the original image. https://www.evernote.com/shard/s6/sh/5713b6d8-ce5e-404f-ad69-d214aa5d33b2/41095290150c193c1bd9b6db800fdfe9 I'm not sure if skitch or imgur resampled the PNG or if your phone just scaled it down well.

Comment: +1 for the "too close" design

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is currently very difficult to tap on the tags field on various devices running the official Appstore app on iOS8. The tags field is rendering underneath the markdown toolbar. This was caused by changes to the keyboard on iOS8, such as the addition of the predictive keyboard bar.

As a **temporary workaround**, until the next update is released, users can follow these steps:

1. Hide the markdown toolbar by tapping on the leftmost (triple arrow) button:

   > [image]
2. Tap on the tags field or any area on that row:

   > [image]

To clarify, this has been fixed in the beta version of the app.

Answer (score 0):

For those with access to the alpha/beta builds this appears to be fixed quite nicely on version 1.1.0.119 of the app.

Comment: It's funny, I misunderstood your initial bug report as saying that the tags field should fully visible everytime (and even after adding a tag). I see what you mean though.

Comment: Yes - it needed an edit for clarity. Also, your comment on versions was a bit after I included those details. :-)